# Type Error : Unhashable dict in python while subtracting values in two dict

Tags: python

```
all_files_list = {}
all_files_list['dir'] = [
    ('file1.txt', 10282020),
    ('file2.txt', 10282020),
    ('file3.txt', 10282020)]

modified_file_list = {}
modified_file_list['dir'] = [
    ('file1.txt', 10282020, {data : {'status1' : 1, 'status2' : 0}}),
    ('file2.txt', 10282020, {data : {'status3' : 0, 'status4' : 0}}),
    (None, None, None)]

file_to_modify = list(set(all_files_list['dir']) - set(modified_file_list['dir']))
```

when i'm doing this its giving `Type Error : Unhashable type: 'dict'`

Requirement - From modified_file_list['dir'] we should subtract those file only whose sum of status is = 0. key name status can be different every time.

for example: `('file2.txt', 10282020, {data : {'status3' : 0, 'status4' : 0}})`
status 3 and status 4 sum is zero so we can subtract these files and not insert them in "file_to_modify".

but for `('file1.txt', 10282020, {data : {'status1' : 1, 'status2' : 0}})` sum is not zero, then directly this should be inserted in "file_to_modify" while subtracting.

all_file_list['dir'] contains filename and file modified time. like wise modified file list contains filename, file modified time and a status dict as illustrated before. So i want to subtract on the basis of filename and file modified time. so that if same file name arrives again it will have different modified time so we should consider that file and insert in file_to_modify

expected output -
file_to_modify = [('file1.txt', 10282020, {"data": {'status1': 1, 'status2': 0}}), ('file3.txt', 10282020, None)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manipulate more the data, you cannot only use it like this

- temporary `all_files_dict` to access data of `all_files_list`
- temporary `modified_files_dict`  to access data of `modified_file_list`

Then iterate over the `all_files_dict` and use the data of `modified_files_dict`  to decide whether or not to keep it

```
all_files_list = {
    'dir': [('file1.txt', 10282020),
            ('file2.txt', 10282020),
            ('file3.txt', 10282020)]}

modified_file_list = {
    'dir': [('file1.txt', 10282020, {"data": {'status1': 1, 'status2': 0}}),
            ('file2.txt', 10282020, {"data": {'status3': 0, 'status4': 0}}),
            (None, None, None)]}

all_files_dict = dict(all_files_list['dir'])
modified_files_dict = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in modified_file_list['dir'] if x[0]}

file_to_modify = []
for filename, vals in all_files_dict.items():
    if filename in modified_files_dict:
        sum_status = sum(modified_files_dict[filename][1]['data'].values())
        if sum_status == 0:
            continue
    file_to_modify.append((filename, vals, modified_files_dict.get(filename, [None, None])[1]))

print(file_to_modify)
# [('file1.txt', 10282020, {"data": {'status1': 1, 'status2': 0}}), ('file3.txt', 10282020, None)]
```

Comment: all_file_list['dir'] contains filename and file modified time. like wise modified file list contains filename, file modified time and a status dict as illustrated before. So i want to subtract on the basis of filename and file modified time. so that if same file name arrives again it will have different modified time so we should consider that file and insert in file_to_modify

Comment: expected output - file_to_modify = [('file1.txt', 10282020, {"data": {'status1': 1, 'status2': 0}}), ('file3.txt', 10282020, None)]

Comment: This should work, let me try this in my actual code. Thank you :)